# How to correct this python3.4 lxml multicore detection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, lxml

Trying to build lxml with static dependencies

```
> # python3.4 setup.py bdist_egg --static-deps


...

config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing libtool commands
make: Warning: Ignoring DistributedMake -j option
make: Fatal error: No dmake max jobs argument after -j flag
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 230, in <module>
   **setup_extra_options()
File "setup.py", line 144, in setup_extra_options
   STATIC_CFLAGS, STATIC_BINARIES)
File "/export/home/drlou/lxml/setupinfo.py", line 57, in ext_modules
   multicore=OPTION_MULTICORE)
File "/export/home/drlou/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 348, in build_libxml2xslt
   cmmi(configure_cmd, libiconv_dir, multicore, **call_setup)
File "/export/home/drlou/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 285, in cmmi
   cwd=build_dir, **call_setup)
File "/export/home/drlou/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 268, in call_subprocess
  raise Exception('Command "%s" returned code %s' % (cmd_desc, returncode))
Exception: Command "make -j6" returned code 256
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
--multicore=1
```

to the build command line (untested).

Comment: Martin - Perfect, and thanks for that. Works!
I still can't get around the fundamental issue, though, that (I'd thought?) setuptools should be able to detect multicore? Seems they always have in the past.

Comment: It did detect multicore, and tried to use it. The problem is that it assumed GNU make or compatible, and your make is not compatible, as it requires a space between the -j and the 6 (i.e. "-j" "6" instead of "-j6"). You might want to submit a patch to always make it two arguments, since GNU make also supports passing this in two arguments.

Comment: Martin - This is a great catch. I'll get on it.